# How to add numbers above a pandas dataframe's column names?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have this dataframe:

```
    Name   Salary  Field
0   Megan  30000   Botany
1   Ann    24000   Psychology
2   John   24000   Police
3   Mary   45000   Genetics
4   Jay    60000   Data Science
```

I want to add some 0-indexed numbers above the column names, but I'd also want to keep the column names. I want to reach this form:

```
     0       1       2
    Name   Salary  Field
0   Megan  30000   Botany
1   Ann    24000   Psychology
2   John   24000   Police
3   Mary   45000   Genetics
4   Jay    60000   Data Science
```

How can I do that with pandas and Python?

Comment: Adding numbers above will either a) change the column name, or b) add a new level.  in any case, you won't be able to slice out a column in the same way.  Is that ok?

Comment: It's OK, thanks for mentioning that this will affect the slicing process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to create a new dataframe:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(enumerate(df)))
```

As expected:

```
#        0      1             2
#     Name Salary         Field
# 0  Megan  30000        Botany
# 1    Ann  24000    Psychology
# 2   John  24000        Police
# 3   Mary  45000      Genetics
# 4    Jay  60000  Data Science
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick way

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.values,
                      columns = [ list(range(df.shape[1])), df.columns]
                      )
```

I'm sure there is a more elegant way